# SAS: Convert multiple columns to numeric

Tags: sas

I have imported a dataset into SAS using `proc import` from an excel spreadsheet. All of the numeric columns are now characters, so is there a way of (cleanly) converting them all to numeric.

It doesn't work if I do the following:

```
data rf;
    set rf;

    rfage = input(rfage, 8.);
run;
```

So, I need to create a new column, then drop the old one:

```
data rf;
    set rf;

    rfage1 = input(rfage, 8.);
    drop rfage;
    rename rfage = rfage;
run;
```

Is there a way that I can convert a large number of columns to numeric (either this way, or a better way), using arrays and a `do over` loop if possible?

```
data rf;
    set rf;

    array to_numeric rfage -- rfprevparticipant;
    do over to_numeric;
        * Some function to convert to numeric here;
    end;
run;
```

Alternatively, is there a way to change `proc import` to import numeric columns correctly in the first place?

Comment: What type of file did you use PROC IMPORT to read?  If it was a delimited text file then skip the PROC IMPORT and just write the data step to read the file yourself.  If you have no idea how to do that you could use the code that PROC IMPORT generated as a model.  If you are reading from an actual XLSX file then make sure that the numeric columns only have numeric cells in them.

Comment: It was an .xlsx file, it was supplied by our database provider and it is notorious for being tricky - the columns are all numeric but it imports as characters every time

Comment: There are two causes of numeric columns in an XLSX file being seen as character by proc import. Some cell in the column has a character string.  All of the cells in a column are empty.  For the latter just drop the original variable.  If you need the empty column then define it as numeric.

Comment: I've checked the oriinal source - there are no strings in the columns they are just 0 and 1, but there are some empty cells (should indicate missing)

Comment: The empty cells are not empty then. Instead they contain some invisible character, such as a space.  Or the 1 and 0 are strings and not numbers.  Or if you learned to type on an old typewriter the 1's are lower case l or the the 0;s are uppercase O.

Comment: An helpful opensource macro `char2num` from Roland Rashleigh-Berry:  http://www.datasavantconsulting.com/roland/Spectre/utilmacros.zip

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this as a template

```
data have;

   array r $ rf1 - rf10;

   do _N_ = 1 to 10;
      do over r;
         r = put(rand('integer', 1, 10), 8.);
      end;
      output;
   end;

run;

data want;
   set have;

   array rnum num_rf1 - num_rf10;
   array r $ rf1 - rf10;

   do over rnum;
      rnum = input(r, 8.);
   end;
run;
```

Comment: That works fine - only problem is now that I don't know how to drop the char columns then rename the new columns to the old names

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to fix it at the source.
Something causes PROC IMPORT to *guess* that these columns are characters, and there could be **a lot** of valid reasons:

- Header with more than 1 row
- NULL, NA, N/A values

Alternatively, if you want to convert all characters variables to numeric in a table you could use the following macro that generates the drop and rename so that you keep the original names.

```
data have;
set sashelp.cars;
run;

%macro chartonum(in, out);
    /* get char var names and position */
    proc contents noprint data=have out=varname(keep=name type npos where=(type=2));
    run;

    /* yields char vars in the order they appear in the data set*/
    proc sort;
        by npos;
    run;

    data _null_;
        do i=1 to nobs;
            set varname nobs=nobs end=end;
            call symput('mac'||left(put(i,4.)),name);     /*creates macro variables for name of vars*/
            call symput('num'||left(put(i,4.)),'num'||left(put(i,4.)));   /*creates new macro numeric vars*/

            if end then call symput('end',put(nobs,8.));   /*determines number of variables, 1 per obs*/
        end;
    run;

    data &out.(drop= %do i=1 %to &end;&&mac&i %end;
        rename=(
        %do i=1 %to &end;
            &&num&i=&&mac&i
        %end;
    ));
    %do i=1 %to &end;
        set &in.;

        /*create numeric macro vars, which resolve to num1-num5*/
        &&num&i=input(&&mac&i,5.);
    %end;
    run;

%mend;

%chartonum(have, want);
```

Comment: I agree about fixing it at source - but I'm at a loss!

This solution works if i want to convert all char columns, but it's only a subset of the char columns that I want to convert, others should be kept as chars

Comment: how many columns are we talking about? is there a prefix/suffix that can be use to recognize them? would it be better to put as parameter only the one to exclude or to include in the conversion?

Comment: ~50 columns, across 11 datasets. They are (usually) sequential, but don't have common prefixes

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Kermit's macro. Instead of using the `where=` option in the `proc contents`, define the `have` dataset with only the variables you want to change.

I'll walk through an example. The example below is going to convert some numeric vars into char vars because it's easier to illustrate. First, we'll need some test data, so I'm creating a copy of `sashelp.baseball` in the work library.

```
* create test data;
data baseball;
set sashelp.baseball;
run;
```

The primary work up front is to create a template of the data you want to change. In the example, I am using a variable list in the `keep` statement to identify the numeric vars I want to convert. Variables lists are really powerful for specifying many variables without typing each one. The style I used is just one of a few different ways to write variable lists.

```
data templt;
stop;
set baseball;
* use variable lists to easily address large groups of vars;
keep YrMajor-numeric-Salary; * keeps only numeric vars even if char vars are between them;
run;
```

The variable list in the `keep` statement captures all the numeric variables between `YrMajor` and `Salary` ignoring any character variables between them. The number of variables kept is 11. Notice that the template has no data because it's not needed for this exercise. We only need the metadata about the variables.

Once the template is defined, use it in the macro to create the code needed to change the data. Here's my version of the macro.

```
%macro change(in, out, tmplt);

* capture var names from template into a macro var;
proc sql noprint;
select
    name into :varnames separated by ' '
from sashelp.vcolumn
where
    libname = 'WORK'
    and memname = "%upcase(&tmplt)"
order by npos
;
quit;

%let varcnt = %sysfunc(countw(&varnames));
%put NOTE: &=varcnt  &=varnames;

data &out (drop=%do i = 1 %to &varcnt; oldvar&i %end;);
set &in
    (rename=(
        %do i = 1 %to &varcnt;
            %scan(&varnames, &i)=oldvar&i
        %end;
    ));
length %do i = 1 %to &varcnt; %scan(&varnames, &i) %end; $12;
%do i = 1 %to &varcnt;
    %scan(&varnames, &i) %str(=) put(oldvar&i, best12.);
%end;
run;

%mend;
```

Here's part of the log showing the code generated by the macro.

```
NOTE: VARCNT=11  VARNAMES=YrMajor CrAtBat CrHits CrHome CrRuns CrRbi CrBB nOuts nAssts nError Salary
MPRINT(CHANGE):   data baseball2 (drop= oldvar1 oldvar2 oldvar3 oldvar4 oldvar5 oldvar6 oldvar7 oldvar8 oldvar9 oldvar10 oldvar11);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   set baseball (rename=( YrMajor=oldvar1 CrAtBat=oldvar2 CrHits=oldvar3 CrHome=oldvar4 CrRuns=oldvar5 CrRbi=oldvar6 
CrBB=oldvar7 nOuts=oldvar8 nAssts=oldvar9 nError=oldvar10 Salary=oldvar11 ));
MPRINT(CHANGE):   length YrMajor CrAtBat CrHits CrHome CrRuns CrRbi CrBB nOuts nAssts nError Salary $12;
MPRINT(CHANGE):   YrMajor = put(oldvar1, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrAtBat = put(oldvar2, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrHits = put(oldvar3, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrHome = put(oldvar4, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrRuns = put(oldvar5, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrRbi = put(oldvar6, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   CrBB = put(oldvar7, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   nOuts = put(oldvar8, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   nAssts = put(oldvar9, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   nError = put(oldvar10, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   Salary = put(oldvar11, best12.);
MPRINT(CHANGE):   run;
```